# Android keyboard hides itself, showing blank space below, after coming back from screensaver

Tags: android, view, keyboard, android-edittext, sleep

I am working on an android app and really enjoying it too. But today, I got stuck on a  small problem with soft keyboard.

I have an `EditText` at the bottom of the screen and when user clicks on it a keyboard pops up ,resizing the entire view to show the `EditText` above keyboard, which is as it should be.  But if user doesn't do anything for sometime, phone sleeps and screen gets locked with the keyboard still present in the screen. When phone comes back after sleep, the keyboard seems to hide itself, leaving my views in a resized state. A blank space is shown where the keyboard has been present..I would be happy if

1. The keyboard remains there after
   coming back from sleep..
2. Let the keyboard hide,but my views
   should go back to original size, ie
   without any blank space..

What can I do to achieve any of these?

Comment: I can't believe no one experienced it before..:(

Comment: what version of android? 2.3.3 has a known bug when things like the keyboard don't always appear

Comment: Thanks for the reply @steelbytes..I am using android 2.1..

Comment: Call [`requestFocus`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()) on the `editText` in the `OnResume` method. Does this make the keyboard appear?

Comment: Did you tried this one?

   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_direction_3);
  getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
    android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: i am experiencing the same issue with xamarin forms, can we some how fix this?